# Coded UI HtmlTable's Rows and Cells properties are null

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, htmltable-control

I try to automate a test, try to reach an `HtmlTable` object, but it's not that easy.. If I add it to the `UImap`, the designer file shows it as a HtmlTable, but I can't locate it from the map.
If I try to find it manually it works, but the Rows and Cells properties are nulls but the `CellCount` and `RowCount` are showing the correct values.
The only way I can reach the cells is to separate the HtmlTable to two HtmlCustom controls.
The first one's "`TagName`" is "`THEAD`" and the second's is "`TBODY`".

```
        HtmlCustom parent = new HtmlCustom(htmlTable);
        parent.SearchProperties.Add("TagName","TBODY");
        parent.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName","HtmlTag.TBODY");

       var firstchild = parent.GetChildren();
        foreach(var secondchild in firstchild)
        {
            var thrdchild = secondchild.GetChildren();

            foreach (var cells in thrdchild)
            {
                //do sg
            }
        }
```

After the separation I can get the children with the `GetChildren()` function (basically the Rows), but in some cases the `GetChildren` returns `null`..
I can't find anything about this issue. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Mostly the `GetCell` function works correctly and returns the cell itself, but in a few cases (5%) it can't find the cell. Just like the `GetChildren` function. But this is really annoying.
I wrote a little recursive function with a try catch block to catch the `NullReferenceException` and try to get the cell again and again, but it won't help a lot..

Comment: You may need to tweak the search properties and make your table locate-able. No need to make it HtmlCustom. If you have only one table on your page then a slicker way would be to remove everything from SearchFilter and in SearchProperties only keep the TagName as "Table" and remove other search properties. It will sure shot locate the table. After then `GetCell` and `GetRow` should work properly.

Comment: I don't have any search property. I can locate the table manually, the problem is that the Cells and the Rows are null. The RowCount and CellCount works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlCell functions

```
//for verification

var cell=GetCell(2,1);

//Now you can use the assert class for verification

Assert.areequal("CodedUi ", cell.innertext,"values are not matched");

HtmlCell GetCell(UITestControl parent, int row, int column)
{ 
  var cell= new htmlcell(parent);
  cell.Searchproperties.Add(HtmlCell.Propertynames.Rowindex,row);
  cell.Searchproperties.Add(HtmlCell.Propertynames.Columnindex,column);
   retun cell;
}
```

Comment: if you have the parent (must be a table control) you have the same method - "GetCell" on the parent, you dont need to write it yourself...

Comment: I wrote my own GetCell function, but the HtmlTable has his own GetCell property. None of them works. The GetCell property throws a NullReference exception, my handwritten GetCell method just doesn't do anything and returns a null.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

Finally I've solved the problem. Solved is not a correct word, but understood why are the properties and functions working so randomly.

The webpage which I try to test has some dynamic JS elements and the page refreshes itself in every 3 seconds. That's the cause of the irregular behavior of the `HtmlTable`.

Now I try to disable this auto-refreshment somehow in the browser.